# OpenXML Selecting a specific column

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, spreadsheetml

I'm attempting to select a specific column so that I can set it's width automatically but am having little success. Should I not be able to use MSDN's version of GetRow to select the column from the columns collection instead?

```
return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();

return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Column>().Where(r => r.Min== columnNumber && r.Max == columnNumber).First();
```

Am I taking the right approach? FWIW I'm aware of how to create the column from scratch and set the width, but that isn't feasible as I don't know what data is going to be inside the columns when I create them in my constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a columns Object to a Worksheet. Then I made a method that sets the width.

```
Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();
Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(CreateColumnData(1, 1, 14.87));

ws.append(columns);


private static Column CreateColumnData(UInt32 StartColumnIndex, UInt32 EndColumnIndex, double ColumnWidth)
    {
        Column column;
        column = new Column();
        column.Min = StartColumnIndex;
        column.Max = EndColumnIndex;
        column.Width = ColumnWidth;
        column.CustomWidth = true;
        return column;
    }
```

Comment: This way no matter what goes into Column 1, the width will be set to 14.87

Comment: You're exactly right... and I could already do this before... What I need to do is Dynamically select the width of the column based on what is inside of it. :( This is no help. :( @broguyman

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, needed to set width for different columns, but was unable to find solution on the web. Answers provided so  far are just showing  how to create column with specified width, but not how to update dynamically width  of specified column. May be I'm not much familiar with .net's openxml library but DocumentFormat.OpenXml seams not documented well and not intuitive as Office.Interop. As my application was running as azure service I did not have a chance to use Office.Interop. Solution for me was to use closedxml library which simplifies work with openxml documents much like in Office.Interop. You can google it.

Answer (score -1):

He did not write that method. The method comes from a complete article that is able to set the width of a column, based on the length of the cell-value: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/01/11/custom-column-widths-in-excel-open-xml/

Hope this helps! ;)